# Can't retrieve a record after attaching it

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models with many-to-many type relationship defined between them: `User` `belongsToMany` `Post`. After successfully attaching a `$post` to the `$user->posts()`, performing `$user->posts()->find($post->id)` returns `null`. Here is the failing code:

```
if(!$user->posts()->exists($post)){
    $user->posts()->attach($post);
}

// dd($user->posts()->exists($post)) // <-- true, hence the $post was successfully attached
$post = $user->posts()->find($post->id); // <-- null
```

The objective is to access the pivot of the `$post` record. How can I achieve this?

### Relationship configuration

```
// User
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'posts_users', 'user_id', 'post_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('viewed');
}


// Post
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'posts_users')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('viewed');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the relation class `manyToMany` so it's better to do it like this:

```
if(!$user->posts()->where('id', $post->id)->count()){
    $user->posts()->attach($post->id);
}

$post = $user->posts()->where('id', $post->id)->first();
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the relationship is many-to-many

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't

Comment: Could you try with quering the relation: `$user->posts()->get()->find($post->id)`. If this dosen't help - please dump the collection of: `dd($user->posts()->get())`

Comment: The first query didn't work. The `dd($user->posts()->get())` shows, that it does not contain a post with the desired id(3).

Comment: You have to pass id not model while attaching: `$user->posts()->attach($post->id);` In fact the: `dd($user->posts()->exists($post))` if showing that the rocord exists and thats all.

Comment: As i said before, so this check: `if(!$user->posts()->exists($post)){` will brings you false.... so you never get to the `attach`

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But I still can't understand why wasn't `if(!$user->posts()->exists($post)) ...` working. Isn't this check supposed to equal to `true`, when `$post` is not attached to `$user->posts()`?

Comment: `exists` method is checking if the model existing in database not in relation - so if you saved it earlier it is set for existing as a record in DB (no matter the relation).